# stuck while loading JPA entity using ID,getting LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

**again i stuck in following error :**
can anybody help me out..??
I am having one JPA entity say ABC

In that ABC,id is a primary key of data type long.

now i am accessing loading this class using hibernate as below :

```
ABC abc= (ABC )hibernateTemplate.load(ABC.class, id);
```

but it's giving error :
**org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException**: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I tried with debugger but at this point it's returning null (If i try to inspect the value it's showing "java.util.emptystackexception")

can anybody guide me....???
thanks in advance..!

Comment: Did you start a Hibernatesession? Do you use JavaTransactionAPI? Does this live within an JEE-Container or within a pure JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...it was due to some changes made in the db by someone else.
as i was using old JPA entity and table columns are updated by someone it was showing that error.

anyways thanks to dardo,Christian Kuetbach,jayjay...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

check for any relationship in JPA entity

Answer (score 1):

How is your hibernateTemplate being instantiated?

Normal instantiation as per the documentation usually goes something like this:

```
@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
  hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```